# Is there an alternative to Shapeburst Fill that does not fade out in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography

I would like to highlight the areas of certain shapes with a thick stroke. However, the accuracy of my shapes is quite high (which is needed for certain zoom details), so that the "simple line" does not look good where more detailed coastal zones or small land areas are present.

The shapeburst fill does a nice job in filling small areas completely, but I don't like the fading effect. Is there a way to use something similar to the shapeburst but without fading?

Alternative thought: Could I add a copy of my shapes on top and colour it with an offset towards the inside in white to create a similar effect?

Image 1: I don't like it.

[image: Simple Line Feature - does not look good.]

Image 2: Shapeburst does a good job, but I'd like to have it without fading.

[image: Shapeburst is nice, but fading is ugly.]

Comment: Are you using the "Draw line only inside polygon" option?

Comment: I do, but that did not have any effect on the output. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use Shapeburst but just change your settings so it doesn't fade:
[image: Discrete Shapeburst]

Just select `Color ramp`then hit `Edit`. Change `Color 1` and `Color 2` to whatever you want, then the `Type` to `Discreet`.

You can adjust the thickness by setting `Shading style` to `Shade to a set distance` and adjusting that value. (or changing the color ramp offset, but that won't be consistent across features of varying sizes)

Comment: Great, that is it. Exactly what I was looking for, produces the desired result. Thank you for sharing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. Draw the polygon layer with simple fill renderer, colors as you like
2. Use a buffer tool and construct buffers with negative distance.
3. This results in smaller polygons with rounded corners. Draw this layer with white fill colors on top of the original polygon layer.